# How to get Port number of wifiNetwork active currently in android

Tags: android, port, ip-address, wifimanager, wifi

I have an requirement where i need to supply IP address and Port number of currently Connected Wifi network.

I am getting `IP address` using `WifiInfo` class having `getIpAddress()` method.

But i am not able to get Port number..
Kindly provide an appropriate solution../

Comment: 'Port Number' (in terms of Internet Protocol and Unix sockets) is usually assigned by the OS when you connect to a remote address. Or do you mean 'Port' as in wiFi channel?

Comment: @Kerry.. lets say that our device is connected to a wifi Router. i just want to know to which portnumber of that router our device is connected..or that router has assigned us what port number in itself..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Portnumber of Wlan?

You are dooing right by using the WifiManager. There is no WLAN port that's why you can't get the portnumber.