# How to get port number of connected wifi in android?

Tags: android, sockets, port, wifimanager, inet-socket

I want to do print functionality in my android application using wifi printer. For that i have done following. But I dont know how i to get port number.[i have refer the question asked before in which it tells that port number not required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749497/how-to-get-port-number-of-wifinetwork-active-currently-in-android) but how to do without port number?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Port number of wifiNetwork active currently in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749497/how-to-get-port-number-of-wifinetwork-active-currently-in-android)

Comment: is that for some specific device or tab ?

Comment: no...i want to print from any android device...for that only i want

Comment: And i already said that this is repeated question...

Comment: Yes it is, and the answer is the same as well.

Comment: @shivanipatel did you get any solution for this? i am also facing same problem. without port number can we print pdf(which is in internal storage) and that pdf has data in tables and images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WLAN is not connected via a port no. It only has an ip address.

Comment: `InetSocketAddress objEndPoint = new InetSocketAddress(IP,
    port);`for follwing what i should do?

Comment: Here you are trying to connect to a Server Socket which is initialised with a `port no` on a machine with its own `IP`. You need to know these two beforehand

Comment: ok...but port is not needed in WLAN so using ip address how to connect ?

Comment: You need to be connected to the WLAN before connecting to the Server Socket, ie. before doing this `InetSocketAddress objEndPoint = new InetSocketAddress(IP, port);`

Comment: have you found that how to connect printer with wifi? if yes, then please tell me...

Comment: Could you share a reference document ?

Comment: @shivanipatel did you find how to connect InetSocketAddress  without knowing port number? Thanks in advance